# I need to analyze access.log with a precision of one second

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, nginx, report

I'm dealing with a large traffic, between hundreds and thousands HTTP requests per second.

I need to analyze my access.log with a precision of ONE SECOND over some time, e.g. 60 minutes. In other words I'd like to produce a report with 3600 bars, showing total number of requests for each second, ideally each bar should be a stack of coloured http codes (2xx, 4xx, 5xx).

Is there a tool that can produce a report like this? I don't want to track traffic live or stuff like that, just analyze a part of the access.log offline with 1 sec precision.

I need to detect if there are sudden spikes where the traffic suddenly goes up from 500 to e.g. 5000 requests per second flooding the fastcgi app socket and causing timeouts. Access.log is ridiculously big with that traffic and trying to read anything from it is a pain.

Comment: "I'd like to produce a report with 3600 bars" What monitor are you planning on showing this report on?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at awstats. Its a free log analyzer. I have used it in the past and its very flexible. I dont know about the 1 second piece though, you will need to try that out.

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I just started using a combination of Logstash, ElasticSearch, and Kibana to examine my access logs. With this setup, I can create the following graph. Its showing all my logs, one bar is one second worth of logs. I'm also capable of zooming in and out of the graph (down to a 1 second interval). Searching is also very quick-and-easy.

[image: Kibana graph]

This is the tutorial I followed (somewhat) to get things in place. http://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/powerful-analysis-tool-using-logstash-elasticsearch-kibana/

I have just started scratching the surface of what this setup is capable of, but I do know that LogStash is capable of reading in flat files.